# Equivalence of control statements

Tags: if-statement, hyperlink, powerpoint

Is it possible to make an object on a slide hyperlink to different slides depending on the contents of a textbox on the slide in question?

Comment: Yes, it's possible using VBA.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: If you want to use VBA and need help, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but I was mostly just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Steve Rindsberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1667023/steve-rindsberg):

> Yes, it's possible using VBA. Otherwise, no.